# option hover event

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show content in a `<div>` based on the `<option>` hovered in a `<select>` box. How can I achieve this using jQuery across all browsers ? select:hover or option:hover does not seem to solve the problem on IE and chrome.

Comment: Have you already tried to use mouseover()? http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: Tried Google? http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/01/12/ie-jquery-hovering-and-option-elements/

Comment: mouseover, hover and select dont seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link helped me re-invent the select dropdown box, the hover event works perfect across all browsers when applied to an `<a>` tag. With any other tag it will create a problem in one browser or the other.

[Reinventing drop down with CSS and jQuery](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx)

The problem with a traditional select box is that it simply does not accept onHover events across all browsers. Hope this helps someone out there, and `john resig` doesnt need to write another `alladin` framework !